# Connecting MSSQL Server through Zend Framework using FreeTDS library

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, zend-framework, freetds

I'm trying to connect with MSSQL Server but I'm having some difficulties. First, my server is throwing the following error:

> Message: SQLSTATE[HY000] Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (severity 9)

Well, I think I installed FreeTDS successfully, because every check I made shows me that everything is okay.

MSSQL configs:

[image: MSSQL configs]

PDO config:

[image: PDO config]

My attempt to connect:

```
[local : production]
resources.db.adapter = "pdo_mssql"
resources.db.params.pdoType = "dblib"
resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
resources.db.params.driver_options.ReutlocarnDatesAsStrings = true
resources.db.params.dbname = "database"
resources.db.params.host = "server-ip"
resources.db.params.username = "user"
resources.db.params.password = "password"
```

The modules they're installed

```
rodrigo@thx1138 ~   [15:51:16] 
$ php -m | grep "mssql"
mssql

rodrigo@thx1138 ~ [15:51:28] 
$ php -m | grep "pdo_"                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
pdo_dblib
pdo_mysql
```

My freetds.config: http://pastebin.com/qA0XwFVD

My nmap output

```
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-07-02 17:48 BRT
Nmap scan report for host (IP)
Host is up (0.00049s latency).
Not shown: 919 filtered ports, 74 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
21/tcp   open  ftp
25/tcp   open  smtp
80/tcp   open  http
139/tcp  open  netbios-ssn
1433/tcp open  ms-sql-s
3128/tcp open  squid-http
3389/tcp open  ms-wbt-server
```

This is my freetds settings

```
tsql -C                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Compile-time settings (established with the "configure" script)
                            Version: freetds v0.91
             freetds.conf directory: /usr/local/etc
     MS db-lib source compatibility: no
        Sybase binary compatibility: no
                      Thread safety: yes
                      iconv library: yes
                        TDS version: 5.0
                              iODBC: no
                           unixodbc: no
              SSPI "trusted" logins: no
                           Kerberos: no
```

And when I try to connect through FreeTDS got the error:

```
rodrigo@thx1138 ~ 
> $ tsql -S server-ip -U user
Password: 
locale is "LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=pt_BR.UTF-8;LC_TIME=pt_BR.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=pt_BR.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=pt_BR.UTF-8;LC_NAME=pt_BR.UTF-8;LC_ADDRESS=pt_BR.UTF-8;LC_TELEPHONE=pt_BR.UTF-8;LC_MEASUREMENT=pt_BR.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=pt_BR.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
Error 20009 (severity 9):
    Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist
    OS error 111, "Connection refused"
There was a problem connecting to the server
```

Actually some months ago I've already made a successful installation, but to be honest don't know what I've done and unfortunately I've had to format my machine, so my problem is that I can't do it again. I think my problem is between my `dblib` and `FreeTDS` but can't find what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance for any help.

Ubuntu: 14.04
PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.2

Answer (score 1):

When using the `-S` flag for `tsql`, you need to specify the name of a server-section in your `freetds.conf` file.  In your file, you've defined servers named `egServer50` and `localhost`.  If you want to use an IP address directly, you have to use the `-H` flag along with the `-p` flag and not the `-S` flag.

Comment: Thank you for your response. In fact I was using the `tsql` tool wrong, but now I'm getting the this
`Error 20017 (severity 9):
 Unexpected EOF from the server
 OS error 115, "Operation now in progress"
Error 20002 (severity 9):
 Adaptive Server connection failed
There was a problem connecting to the server`

Comment: Just to be more clear. My problem is my connection with PHP. I was trying to test my connection with tsql and noticed that I can't connect with my server.

Comment: Can you show the PHP code you're trying to connect with?

Comment: Actually not. But I'm using Zend Framework, so up there is my connection settings. But this problem will crash any part of my code where I need to use my models.

Comment: OK. Looking through my one working pdo_mssql installation, I set the host name to a `freetds.conf` server section also.  So, you'd set `resources.db.params.host` to be one of the section names in your `freetds.conf` file, e.g. either `egServer50` or `localhost`.

Comment: Even with this alterations it doesn't work, but I'm not give up. I'll try reinstall everything again. Thank you for your time.